# How can I use split() in a string when broadcasting a dataframe's column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take the following dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[0, 1], 'col_2':['here 123', 'here 456']})`

Result:

```
   col_1     col_2
0      0  here 123
1      1  here 456
```

I need to create a 3rd column (broadcasting), using a condition on `col_1`, and splitting the string on `col_2`. This is ok to do:

`df['col_3'] = float('NaN')`

`df.loc[df['col_1'] == 1, ['col_3']] = df['col_2'].str.slice(5, 8)`

Result:

```
   col_1     col_2 col_3
0      0  here 123   NaN
1      1  here 456   456
```

But I need to specify dynamic indexes to split the string on `col_2`, instead of (5, 8).

When I try to run the following code it does not work, because `df['col_2']` is treated as a `Series`:

`df.loc[df['col_1'] == 1, ['col_3']] = df['col_2'].split(' ')[0]`

I'm spending a huge time trying to solve this without needing to iterate the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one liner does the trick.

```
df['col_3']=[y.split(' ')[1] if x==1 else float('nan') for x,y in df[['col_1','col_2']].values]
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems a way. 2 questions: (1) I think I'll will loose my conditional in larger dfs, no? It's important to keep the conditional based on `col_1`.  (2). The NaN values disappears also with the apply() method.

Comment: Okay.  this one liner solves both your questions [ i have updated original answer]

df['col_3']=[y.split(' ')[1] if x==1 else float('nan') for x,y in df[['col_1','col_2']].values]

Comment: Great! Hope one day to get in this level! Rgds

Answer (score 0):

use `np.where` to get which condition to get the split part.

```
df['col_3'] = np.where(df.col_1 == 1, 
                       df['col_2'].str.split().str[-1], 
                       np.nan)
```